# Using PyQtGraph my Surface Plot displays in the bottom left quarter of the window.

Tags: python, macos, opengl, qtgui, pyqtgraph

Here is my code.

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import sys

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w=gl.GLViewWidget()
    w.show()
    w.setCameraPosition(distance=150)

    #just my data
    data=Dataset('200707.nc')


    prec=data.variables['Prec'][5,:59,:59]

    p = gl.GLSurfacePlotItem(z=prec[:] ,shader='heightColor')
    p.shader()['colorMap'] = np.array([0.2, 2, 0.5, 0.2, 1, 1, 0.2, 0, 2])


    w.addItem(p)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

I think the issue could be in the library's interaction with my Mac's pixel layout. Really not sure what it could be or how to resolve it. Should I looking into using a different program?

Comment: Could you provide a proper problem description? What exactly *is* the problem? How should the code behave like instead?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The issue is the plot this graphs is centered in the bottom left quadrant of the window- not the center. http://i.imgur.com/H4WoMfn.png

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have the same problem on my MacBook Pro 2016 15 inch running MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 and Python 3.6. To reproduce it, get a Mac, `sudo pip3 install PyOpenGL pyqtgragh` and run the examples as described in the documentation. That is, `import pyqtgraph.examples; pyqtgraph.examples.run()` in a Python console. Then, in the window that appears, select any of the "3D Graphcs" examples, and you will see that instead of the graph occupying the whole window as it should do, it only occupies the bottom-left quadrant,.

Comment: My friend tried it on Linux and it was fine, and another friend tried it on another Mac and it was the same problem. It looks like a Mac problem.

Comment: I don't have a mac available and will surely never use one in the future; I therefore cannot help here. But @Ray if you understood the question, maybe you can edit it such that the problem becomes more apparent.

Comment: Update, it looks like a scaling issue due to 4K and High DPI. I rescaled my (external) monitor and it displayed fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Macbook Pro. I think something from the version of PyQtGraph you have installed isn't allowing for proper scaling on your (and most Mac) devices.

I haven't really messed around too much, but to get around this I created a new Python environment in Anaconda (to make sure any other dependencies aren't causing this) and installed the version of PyQtGraph that's available through Conda. I don't know if other versions through other sources will work as well, but this one seems to work for me.

If you have Anaconda installed on your computer, simply do the following:

- Create a new Python environment. `conda create -n env_name python=py_ver anaconda`
- Source to your environment. `source activate env_name`
- Install PyQtGraph. `conda install -c anaconda pyqtgraph`

Now when you run your program, it should scale properly.

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue, but making a new env didn't fix it for me...

Answer (score 0):

Had a problem like this after installing vispy on osx. Turns out I just needed to install the latest version of pyqt5 and the problem went away.

`pip install pyqt5`